# how to set media query for a screen such bib that I can not do trial and error in dev tools

Tags: css, media-queries

I did the media queries for responsive behavior and worked well from small to large devices, such as laptops, but someone tried it on a mac and the content became a mess. How can I set de media queries for screen sizes that I dont know? Thanks

Comment: Try different browsers. Also, if you have a desktop and you can't simulate smaller desktops by resizing the browser window, you're doing it wrong. You should not program for specific brands of hardware. Can you point to a website where this happens?

Comment: Please provide some code with specific examples that demonstrate what your problem is - this question is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Media Queries are meant to define specific max and min width.
For unknown large screens, you have 2 options:

1.Setting a fix width when screen size has reached a specific width, so that your contents will always appear the same way.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .page-wrapper {
    width: 1400px;
  }
}
```

2.Take care to set page with to 100% and work with percentages on all main elements (those which might look broken).

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .page-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```